# Issue with Predictive Search Add to Cart Button not working for first product result in Shopify Dawn Theme

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

I'm using Shopify Dawn theme.

In predictive search results, I want to add Quantity selector & Add to cart button beside the product listing.

For the first product result,  tag is not showing, due to which I'm not able to add to cart the product. For rest product items, it works perfectly.

Store URL - https://demostore-theme.myshopify.com
Password - 123

Search with keyword - "de"

1st result - https://prnt.sc/vwKRqVRDTYS3
Console error - https://prnt.sc/M_8u_9O7Mm0e

For rest result - https://prnt.sc/DSWORL0h9FEY (works perfectly)

I have edited this code in predictive-search.liquid

```
{%- for product in predictive_search.resources.products -%}
  <li
    id="predictive-search-option-product-{{ forloop.index }}"
    class="predictive-search__list-item"
    role="option"
    aria-selected="false"
  >
    <a
      href="{{ product.url }}"
      class="predictive-search__item predictive-search__item--link-with-thumbnail link link--text"
      tabindex="-1"
    >
      {%- if product.featured_media != blank -%}
        <img
          class="predictive-search__image"
          src="{{ product.featured_media | image_url: width: 150 }}"
          alt="{{ product.featured_media.alt }}"
          width="50"
          height="{{ 50 | divided_by: product.featured_media.preview_image.aspect_ratio }}"
        >
      {%- endif -%}
      <div class="predictive-search__item-content{% unless settings.predictive_search_show_vendor or settings.predictive_search_show_price %} predictive-search__item-content--centered{% endunless %}">
        {%- if settings.predictive_search_show_vendor -%}
          <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'accessibility.vendor' | t }}</span>
          <div class="predictive-search__item-vendor caption-with-letter-spacing">
            {{ product.vendor }}
          </div>
        {%- endif -%}
        <p class="predictive-search__item-heading h5">{{ product.title | escape }}</p>
        {%- if settings.predictive_search_show_price -%}
          {% render 'price', product: product, use_variant: true, show_badges: false %}
        {%- endif -%}
      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Customization for Add to Cart -->
    <div class="quick-add no-js-hidden">
      {%- liquid
        assign section_id = section.id
        assign product_form_id = 'quick-add-' | append: section_id | append: product.id
        assign qty_rules = false
        if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min > 1 or product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.max != null or product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.increment > 1
          assign qty_rules = true
        endif
      -%}
      {%- if product.variants.size > 1 or qty_rules -%}
        <modal-opener data-modal="#QuickAdd-{{ product.id }}">
          <button
            id="{{ product_form_id }}-submit"
            type="submit"
            name="add"
            class="quick-add__submit button button--full-width button--secondary{% if horizontal_quick_add %} card--horizontal__quick-add animate-arrow{% endif %}"
            aria-haspopup="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="{{ product_form_id }}-submit title-{{ section_id }}-{{ product.id }}"
            data-product-url="{{ product.url }}"
          >
            {{ 'products.product.choose_options' | t }}
            {%- if horizontal_quick_add -%}
              <span class="icon-wrap">{% render 'icon-arrow' %}</span>
            {%- endif -%}
            {%- render 'loading-spinner' -%}
          </button>
        </modal-opener>
        <quick-add-modal id="QuickAdd-{{ product.id }}" class="quick-add-modal">
          <div
            role="dialog"
            aria-label="{{ 'products.product.choose_product_options' | t: product_name: product.title | escape }}"
            aria-modal="true"
            class="quick-add-modal__content global-settings-popup"
            tabindex="-1"
          >
            <button
              id="ModalClose-{{ product.id }}"
              type="button"
              class="quick-add-modal__toggle"
              aria-label="{{ 'accessibility.close' | t }}"
            >
              {% render 'icon-close' %}
            </button>
            <div id="QuickAddInfo-{{ product.id }}" class="quick-add-modal__content-info"></div>
          </div>
        </quick-add-modal>
      {%- else -%}
        <product-form data-section-id="{{ section.id }}">
          {%- form 'product',
            product,
            id: product_form_id,
            class: 'form',
            novalidate: 'novalidate',
            data-type: 'add-to-cart-form'
          -%}
            <!-- Qty Selection -->
            <div
              id="Quantity-Form-{{ section.id }}"
              class="product-form__input product-form__quantity{% if settings.inputs_shadow_vertical_offset != 0 and settings.inputs_shadow_vertical_offset < 0 %} product-form__quantity-top{% endif %}"
              {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
            >
              {% comment %} TODO: enable theme-check once `item_count_for_variant` is accepted as valid filter {% endcomment %}
              {% # theme-check-disable %}
              {%- assign cart_qty = cart | item_count_for_variant: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id -%}
              {% # theme-check-enable %}

              <div class="price-per-item__container">
                <quantity-input class="quantity" data-url="{{ product.url }}" data-section="{{ section.id }}">
                  <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="minus" type="button">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">
                      {{- 'products.product.quantity.decrease' | t: product: product.title | escape -}}
                    </span>
                    {% render 'icon-minus' %}
                  </button>
                  <input
                    class="quantity__input"
                    type="number"
                    name="quantity"
                    id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}"
                    data-cart-quantity="{{ cart_qty }}"
                    data-min="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min }}"
                    min="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min }}"
                    {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.max != null %}
                      data-max="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.max }}"
                      max="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.max }}"
                    {% endif %}
                    step="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.increment }}"
                    value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min }}"
                    form="{{ product_form_id }}"
                  >
                  <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="plus" type="button">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">
                      {{- 'products.product.quantity.increase' | t: product: product.title | escape -}}
                    </span>
                    {% render 'icon-plus' %}
                  </button>
                </quantity-input>
                {%- liquid
                  assign volume_pricing_array = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_price_breaks | sort: 'quantity' | reverse
                  assign current_qty_for_volume_pricing = cart_qty | plus: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min
                  if cart_qty > 0
                    assign current_qty_for_volume_pricing = cart_qty | plus: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.increment
                  endif
                -%}
                {%- if product.quantity_price_breaks_configured? -%}
                  <price-per-item
                    class="no-js-hidden"
                    id="Price-Per-Item-{{ section.id }}"
                    data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"
                    data-variant-id="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
                  >
                    {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_price_breaks.size > 0 -%}
                      {%- assign variant_price_compare = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price -%}
                      <div class="price-per-item">
                        {%- if variant_price_compare -%}
                          <dl class="price-per-item--current">
                            <dt class="visually-hidden">
                              {{ 'products.product.price.regular_price' | t }}
                            </dt>
                            <dd>
                              <s class="variant-item__old-price">
                                {{ variant_price_compare | money_with_currency }}
                              </s>
                            </dd>
                          </dl>
                        {%- endif -%}
                        {%- if current_qty_for_volume_pricing < volume_pricing_array.last.minimum_quantity -%}
                          {%- assign variant_price = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price
                            | money_with_currency
                          -%}
                          <span class="price-per-item--current">
                            {{- 'products.product.volume_pricing.price_at_each' | t: price: variant_price -}}
                          </span>
                        {%- else -%}
                          {%- for price_break in volume_pricing_array -%}
                            {%- if current_qty_for_volume_pricing >= price_break.minimum_quantity -%}
                              {%- assign price_break_price = price_break.price | money_with_currency -%}
                              <span class="price-per-item--current">
                                {{- 'products.product.volume_pricing.price_at_each' | t: price: price_break_price -}}
                              </span>
                              {%- break -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                          {%- endfor -%}
                        {%- endif -%}
                      </div>
                    {%- else -%}
                      {%- assign variant_price = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price
                        | money_with_currency
                      -%}
                      {%- assign variant_price_compare = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.compare_at_price -%}
                      <div class="price-per-item">
                        {%- if variant_price_compare -%}
                          <dl class="price-per-item--current">
                            <dt class="visually-hidden">
                              {{ 'products.product.price.regular_price' | t }}
                            </dt>
                            <dd>
                              <s class="variant-item__old-price">
                                {{ variant_price_compare | money_with_currency }}
                              </s>
                            </dd>
                            <dt class="visually-hidden">
                              {{ 'products.product.price.sale_price' | t }}
                            </dt>
                            <dd>
                              <span class="price-per-item--current">
                                {{- 'products.product.volume_pricing.price_at_each' | t: price: variant_price -}}
                              </span>
                            </dd>
                          </dl>
                        {%- else -%}
                          <span class="price-per-item--current">
                            {{- 'products.product.volume_pricing.price_at_each' | t: price: variant_price -}}
                          </span>
                        {%- endif -%}
                      </div>
                    {%- endif -%}
                  </price-per-item>
                {%- endif -%}
              </div>
              <div class="quantity__rules caption no-js-hidden" id="Quantity-Rules-{{ section.id }}">
                {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.increment > 1 -%}
                  <span class="divider">
                    {{-
                      'products.product.quantity.multiples_of'
                      | t: quantity: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.increment
                    -}}
                  </span>
                {%- endif -%}
                {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min > 1 -%}
                  <span class="divider">
                    {{-
                      'products.product.quantity.minimum_of'
                      | t: quantity: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min
                    -}}
                  </span>
                {%- endif -%}
                {%- if page_titleroduct.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.max != null -%}
                  <span class="divider">
                    {{-
                      'products.product.quantity.maximum_of'
                      | t: quantity: product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.max
                    -}}
                  </span>
                {%- endif -%}
              </div>
              {%- if product.quantity_price_breaks_configured? -%}
                <volume-pricing class="parent-display no-js-hidden" id="Volume-{{ section.id }}">
                  {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_price_breaks.size > 0 -%}
                    <span class="caption-large">{{ 'products.product.volume_pricing.title' | t }}</span>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled no-js-hidden">
                      <li>
                        <span>{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_rule.min }}+</span>
                        {%- assign price = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.price | money_with_currency -%}
                        <span data-text="{{ 'products.product.volume_pricing.price_at_each' | t: price: variant_price }}">
                          {{- 'sections.quick_order_list.each' | t: money: price -}}
                        </span>
                      </li>
                      {%- for price_break in product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_price_breaks -%}
                        {%- assign price_break_price = price_break.price | money_with_currency -%}
                        <li class="{%- if forloop.index >= 3 -%}show-more-item hidden{%- endif -%}">
                          <span>
                            {{- price_break.minimum_quantity -}}
                            <span aria-hidden="true">+</span></span
                          >
                          <span data-text="{{ 'products.product.volume_pricing.price_at_each' | t: price: price_break_price }}">
                            {{- 'sections.quick_order_list.each' | t: money: price_break_price -}}
                          </span>
                        </li>
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </ul>
                    {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.quantity_price_breaks.size >= 3 -%}
                      <show-more-button>
                        <button
                          class="button-show-more link underlined-link"
                          id="Show-More-{{ section.id }}"
                          type="button"
                        >
                          <span class="label-show-more label-text"
                            ><span aria-hidden="true">+ </span>{{ 'products.facets.show_more' | t }}
                          </span>
                        </button>
                      </show-more-button>
                    {%- endif -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
                </volume-pricing>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
            <!-- Qty Selection End -->

            <input
              type="hidden"
              name="id"
              value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
              class="product-variant-id"
              {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available == false %}
                disabled
              {% endif %}
            >

            <button
              id="{{ product_form_id }}-submit"
              type="submit"
              name="add"
              class="quick-add__submit button button--full-width button--secondary{% if horizontal_quick_add %} card--horizontal__quick-add{% endif %}"
              aria-haspopup="dialog"
              aria-labelledby="{{ product_form_id }}-submit title-{{ section_id }}-{{ product.id }}"
              aria-live="polite"
              data-sold-out-message="true"
              {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available == false %}
                disabled
              {% endif %}
            >
              <span>
                {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available -%}
                  {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                {%- else -%}
                  {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                {%- endif -%}
              </span>
              <span class="sold-out-message hidden">
                {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
              </span>
              {%- if horizontal_quick_add -%}
                <span class="icon-wrap">{% render 'icon-plus' %}</span>
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- render 'loading-spinner' -%}
            </button>
          {%- endform -%}
        </product-form>
      {%- endif -%}
    </div>

    <!-- Customization for Add to Cart END -->
  </li>
{%- endfor -%}
```

The Add to Cart button should work properly for all the search result products (especilly the first product result).